# Jenkins multiproject repository

Tags: spring, git, jenkins, github, integrate

Hi my project on github looks like :

- Backend

  - gateway-server
  - authorization-server
  - services

    - restaurant-service
- Mobile
- Web

I tried to connect Jenkins to gateway-server.

[image]

If I have Jenkinsfile on main folder(on repo) it is work.

[image]

I tried path /Backend/gateway-server, /Backend/gateway-server/, Backend/gateway-server, Backend/gateway-server and no one work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first `gateway-server`, meaning a path *Within* the currently checked-out repository (`Backend`)

That might be enough to sparse-checkout that single folder.